# Searching an element in Chrome Browser after page load in Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to search for an element in Chrome after page load on a particular page. However, when I inspect the page, I notice that the HTML tags are not loading dynamically once the page loads. Hence, the driver is searching for the element after page load and the elements available are still the ones which were present before page load and the search is failing. I have tried all the locator techniques. Also used `Thread.sleep` and `wait` commands to wait for the page to load, but to no avail. Let me know if there is an alternative for such a problem.

Comment: Your code trials and relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can this be a defect in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question might not be complete, the best way (to my knowledge) to wait for a page load in java is:

```
new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver, pageLoadTimeout).until(
      webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, i try to check whether the element is displayed and enabled by using  either id, xpath, or name to find it. 
You can add this to your code, and apply a break point. it might be there but might also be hidden. without a stacktrace of the error is difficult to know what is causing you issues. hope this helps.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath);
if (element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()) {
    element.click();
}
```